# How can you minimize the number of new lines of code (not using a string class methods)?

Tags: c#

```
private static void Main() 
    { 
        var stringsOne = new[] {"aaa", "bbb", "ccc"}; 
        var sb = new StringBuilder(); 
        foreach (var s in stringsOne) 
        { 
            sb.Append(s + " "); 
        } 
        var concat = sb.ToString(); 

        Console.WriteLine(concat.Substring(0,concat.Length-1)); 
        Console.ReadKey(); 
    }
```

Comment: could you please more clear about the requirement?

Comment: Might be better off on code review, rather than stack overflow. That being said, there isn't really a better way to write it while using the optimised StringBuilder, even with string extensions. The only thing I can see is the superfluous brackets with the foreach.

Comment: Why is the requirement not to use `string` class? `string.Join(" ", stringsOne)` will do exactly the same, internally it uses `StringBuilder` anyway.

Comment: Or you could just write `Console.WriteLine("aaa bbb ccc");` to get rid of the lines and to still get the same result. But I don't think that's what you want.

Answer (score 1):

you can try this, it is with minimized lines:

```
        var stringsOne = new[] { "aaa", "bbb", "ccc" };
        var sb = new StringBuilder();
        stringsOne.Select(p => p).ToList().ForEach(q => sb.Append(q+" "));
        Console.WriteLine(sb);
```

No ToString or Substring method is used

Answer (score 1):

select each char by `SelectMany` method and convert it to array and append to StringBuilder.

```
var strings = new StringBuilder();  
        strings.Append((new[] { "aaa", "bbb", "ccc" }).SelectMany(str => (str + " ").ToArray()).Reverse().Skip(1).Reverse().ToArray());
```

even you can simply skip the StringBuilder:
    Console.WriteLine(String.Join(" ", new[] { "aaa", "bbb", "ccc" }));

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use:

```
 var stringsOne = new[] { "aaa", "bbb", "ccc" };
        var sb = new StringBuilder();
stringsOne.ToList().ForEach(q => sb.Append(q + " "));
 Console.WriteLine(sb);
```

Answer (score 0):

If your goal  is to output, then there's no need to use `StringBuilder` at all:

```
var stringsOne = new[] { "aaa", "bbb", "ccc" };
for (int i = 0; i < stringsOne.Length; i++)
    Console.Write(i == stringsOne.Length - 1 ? "{0}" : "{0} ", stringsOne[i]);
Console.ReadKey();
```

Answer (score 0):

This does the same job:

```
var stringsOne = new[] { "aaa", "bbb", "ccc" };

var concat = String.Join(" ", stringsOne);

Console.WriteLine(concat);
```

You could always do it as this:

```
Console.WriteLine(String.Join(" ", new[] { "aaa", "bbb", "ccc" }));
```